# DropDown value selection using espresso android with dynamic element id's

Tags: android-espresso

```
PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer(@xxxxxxxx)
--ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView(@yyyyyyyy)
  --RelativeLayout(@zzzzzzz)
    ImageView
    TextView
  --RelativeLayout(@aaaaaaaa)
    ImageView
    TextView
  --RelativeLayout(@aaaaaaaa)
    ImageView
    TextView
```

I want to know how to access the the TextView in RelativeLayout 2 using espresso android automation, as `@id` is not present and values are assigned dynamically.

The above is the dropdown list and I want to click second choice.

e.g like when we search item in any search box we get list populated. And I want to click the second one in the list populated. All the element id's are dynamic.

Answer (score 10):

I was struggling with this issue and I found that you need to use a combination of `withText` to select the view and an option called `RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup()` which will try and find the matching text within views such as the autocomplete view and it is actually designed for this purpose.

It should look something like;

```
onView(withText("matching text"))
.inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup())
.perform(click());
```

Answer (score 6):

You maybe be able to just do

```
onData(anything())
    .atPosition(1)
    .perform(click());
```

However, that assumes only one adapter view. If you have others, you'll need to somehow pick out that `ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView`.

I know you said all IDs are dynamic, but is there some ancestor view which you could pick out by ID? If so, you could do something like

```
onData(anything())
    .inAdapterView(isDescendantOfA(withId(someAncestorId)))
    .atPosition(1)
    .perform(click());
```

As a last resort, we could match on class name, but it would be a bit fragile:

```
onData(anything())
    .inAdapterView(withClassName(equalTo(
        "android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView")))
    .atPosition(1)
    .perform(click());
```

Comment: Yes every id is dynamic in popup and when I see the Tree View(in android Studio) for this popup it is not displaying in MainSearchActivity but its the different Action in tree view as PopupWindow:@xxxxxxxx. Now when I try above code it is throwing error "android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException" as PopupWindow is not in main activity it is not referring the layout in popup Window but referring from MainSearchActivity. I want to set focus to popupwindow when I execute above code, it should refer popupwindow layout instead of MainActivityWindow.

Comment: Any resolution to this? I am having issues with multiple spinners.

Comment: @JPM you should use `inAdapterView`, but which matcher you pass it depends on what your view hierarchy looks like. Do your matchers have different IDs? Pass it `withId`. Different initial selections? Pass it `withSpinnerText`. Different parent containers (with different IDs)? Pass it `isDescendantOfA`.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of both previous answers seems to work for me:

```
Espresso.onData(Matchers.anything())
        .inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup())
        .atPosition(1)
        .perform(ViewActions.click())
```

Comment: This worked for me too, after migrating to Material 1.9.