# Testing autocomplete textview using espresso tool

Tags: android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview, android-espresso

I have an autocomplete textview and I am setting an Adapter view on it to show the list of suggestions. While testing on espresso, I want to select an item position from list of suggestions but, it does not identify the auto complete text view adapter on espresso.

I tried this answer from Stack overflow: 
[DropDown value selection using espresso android with dynamic element id's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438569/dropdown-value-selection-using-espresso-android-with-dynamic-element-ids/29444872#29444872)

But, this did not work for me. Any help on this would be great. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

or you can try instead *onData*. Because *onData* not working for me

```
 onView(withText("Your field name"))
.inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
            .perform(click());
```

Comment: This no longer seems to work in modern Android 10 with Espresso 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem and this is how i did it:

```
onView(withId(R.id.sp_country/*auto complete textview*/)).perform(click());
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is(COUNTRY/*selected value autocomplete collection*/)))
                .inRoot(RootMatchers.withDecorView(not(is(activityActivityTestRule
                        .getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
                .perform(click());
```