# How click in a ImageView whit Autocomplete in Expresso?

Tags: android, autocomplete, automated-tests, android-espresso, android-testing

I have a Autocomplete box, whit a costum **"CityAdapter"**, how can i access the Button/ImageView using expresso test? I filter the costum adapter by **cityName**, so i can find the citys by name.

```
 onView(withId(R.id.autoCompleteCities))
                .perform(typeText(""), closeSoftKeyboard());
         Activity mActivity=mActivityTestRule.getActivity();

onData(instanceOf(CityAdapter.class))
                    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.autoCompleteCities))
                    .atPosition(0)
                    .onChildView(withId(R.id.tvFavourite))
                    .perform(click());
```

Here is a example:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
    onView(withId(R.id.autoCompleteCities))
            .perform(typeText("E"));

    onData(instanceOf(City.class))
            .inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup())
            .atPosition(0)
            .onChildView(withId(R.id.tvFavourite))
            .perform(click());
```

- `onView(~).perform(~)` is to show the `auto complete listview` in the `view-port`.
- `onData(instanceOf(City.class))` This will find the view with the object same as that of the mentioned class (here `City.class`).
- `inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup())` The dropdown menu is on another window than the default window your activity runs in. So we have to specify that we want to search that window.
- `atPosition(0)` Selects the item at the specified position in the `array-list` or `list-view`.
- `onChildView(withId(R.id.tvFavourite))` Selects the child view with the specified ID (here `image-view`).

~ Reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/45368345/8885981

Comment: Thanks very much, your explanation was very usefull! You the best!